# Why isn't my Ruby model method being found?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, controller, relationship

I have models for contacts, groups, and for members who form groups of contacts that are linked via a relationship called members. The members model resolves the many-to-many relationship between contacts and groups using the `:through` attribute.

When I try to add a new method called suggestions to the `Contact` model and call it from my `ContactsController` as shown bellow, I get a message telling me the method isn't found. The ContactsController looks like this:

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:index, :show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :set_contact, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET suggestions
  def suggestions
    recipients_string = params[:recipients_field]

    # Call theContact model to list of all of the groups and individual contacts that aren't already in the recipient list
    # and return them as an html unordered list of clickable links
    @suggestions = contacts.suggestions[recipients_string: :recipients_string]

  end
  ...
  ...
end
```

The model for contacts is as follows:

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :members
  has_many :groups, :through => :members
  default_scope -> { order(name: :asc) }
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :email, presence: true

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :members,
                                :reject_if => :all_blank,
                                :allow_destroy => true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :groups

  def suggestions
      recipients_string = params[:recipients_string]
      # some processing here to ptoduce @suggestions
      @suggestions
  end
end
```

In this use of `Contacts`, I don't want to utilize the relationship, but I notice that when I call `contacts.suggestions`, I get

```
undefined method `suggestions' for #<Contact::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fd75b32c988>
```

Does this have any bearing on why the method isn't being found? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where is `contacts` defined? Since you have an `ActiveRecord::Relation`   in `contacts`, and there is no method called `suggestions` on `ActiveRecord::Relation`, you are seeing this error. Also, in the `Contact` class, where is `params` being defined or passed in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `contacts.suggestions` returns an array of contacts, actually a `Relation` that scopes to the collection of contacts not to a single contact.

`suggestions` is defined as an instance method, hence it should be called on a single instance, not on a collection.

Either change the scope of the method or make sure `contacts` doesn't return a collection.

Comment: Thanks, I understand better now.

Answer (score 1):

That error is telling you that `contacts` is a relation, which is like a collection of Contact records.  (I'd expect it to actually complain that there's no variable or method called `contacts`)

Did you mean to define a `@contact` variable from eg `params[:id]` and then call `.suggestions` on that?

The `suggestions` method in your contact class won't work because it refers to `params`, and these aren't available in the model class unless you pass them through to the method as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you call the methods on a group of contacts.
Your method only exist on one contact

maybe try this:

```
 @suggestions = contacts.map{|contact| contact.suggestions[recipients_string: :recipients_string]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your're calling suggestions() on an ActiveRecord relation, not an individual Contact.  You need to get a specific instance of Contact to call this method.